# User Input Date And Time as SQL Query Parameters in RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, rdlc, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to build an ASP NET website which generates RDLC reports from SQL DataBase data but while trying to use user input by two TextBoxes it just doesn't show anything in the report, can someone tell me why?

Here's the code:

```
   protected void ShowReport()
   {
        DataTable dtOrders = GetOrdersByDates(DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text),
        DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text));
        RV1.Reset();
        RV1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/reports/Report1.rdlc");
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtOrders);
        RV1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
    }

    private DataTable GetOrdersByDates(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;initial Catalog=Operations;integrated Security=true;";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
        string query = @"SELECT Date AS Datet, nUser AS cvUser, NameUser AS User, COUNT(nTicket) AS notravels, CASE WHEN flagout = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS FlaggedOut, '"+ from +"' AS FI, '" + to + "' AS FF FROM Operations WHERE Date BETWEEN '"+ from + "' AND '"+to+"' GROUP BY Date, nUser, NameUser, Flagout ORDER BY cvUser";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I've already done the Stored Procedure on SQL Management Studio and tested setting the query as the stored procedure using this code manually and it works this way

```
 protected void Users_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;initial Catalog=Operations;integrated Security=true;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    string query = @"SELECT CONVERT(datetime, MAX(Date)) AS Datet, nUser AS cvUser, NameUser AS User, COUNT(nTicket) AS notravels, CASE WHEN flagout = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS FlaggedOut, CONVERT (datetime, '2022/12/09 6:0:00.000') AS FI, CONVERT(datetime, '2022/12/10 6:0:00.000') AS FF FROM Operations WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2022/12/09 6:0:00.000') AND CONVERT (datetime, '2022/12/10 5:59:59.999')) GROUP BY Date, nUser, NameUser, Flagout ORDER BY cvUser";


    cmd.CommandText = "PR_CantUsers";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    conn.Close();

    RV1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
    RV1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/reports/Report1.rdlc");
    RV1.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
}
```

Comment: use parameters for the query, that will keep you safe from little bobby table and those issues you have here. there are thousands of examples here and in the whole internet

Comment: An RDLC is HTML format and is a webpage.  In the RDLC is a query to the database which is call Command_Text.  The RDLC is text and you can open with a text editor.  You c# code does not need to work with the RDLC to extract data (except if you want to display as a webpage).  You c# code is directly connecting to the database and putting results into a datatable.  It looks like you query is the same in RDLC and in c#.  The permission may be different database for RDLC and c#.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio and check user/group in log files using explorer under Management.

Comment: Compare the User/Group in logs when using RDLC and c# and see if same account is being used.  RDLC has different method for connecting with credentials to database than through a SQL Client Connection.

Comment: Obligatory [Little Bobby Tables reference](https://xkcd.com/327/). Learn to use [SqlParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#example) instead of inlining tainted user data into the middle of your queries. Not only is using parameters protection against SQL Injection attacks... it's more performant! Since the SQL statements will be binary equal execution plans don't need to be recompiled and so can be cached and reused.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, might as well try some advices here, will update if i find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out how to do it but on Crystal Reports using the same method, first of all i cleared all the code above and rewrite new lines of code, this is how i did it:

```
protected void Fleteros_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptCantFleteros crystalReport10 = new rptCantFleteros();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        CntFleteros dsCntFleteros = new CntFleteros();

        crystalReport10.Load(Server.MapPath("~/reportes/rptCantFleteros.rpt"));
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT nFletero AS cvecamion, Convert(datetime, MAX(Fecha)) as Expr1, COUNT(nTicket) AS noviajes, CASE WHEN flagsalida = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'SI' END AS Destarado, NombreFlete, CONVERT(datetime, @fechaInicio) AS fi, CONVERT(datetime, @fechaFin) AS ff "
                          + "FROM BSCOperacion WHERE (Fecha BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @fechaInicio) AND CONVERT(datetime, @fechaFin))"
                          + "GROUP BY nFletero, NombreFlete, FlagSalida ORDER BY nFletero";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DateTime fechaI = DateTime.Parse(txtFechaInicio.Text);
                DateTime fechaF = DateTime.Parse(txtFechaFin.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaInicio", fechaI);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaFin", fechaF);
                sda.Fill(dsCntFleteros, "cntfleteros");

        crystalReport10.SetDataSource(dsCntFleteros);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport10;
```

Im pretty sure this is the same method for RDLC as well.